# Fuse module for s3fs

Tags: kernel, fuse, s3fs, modprobe

I am trying to install the s3fs software. I however keep coming upon this error:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/s3fs bucketname /mnt
fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
$ modprobe fuse
FATAL: Module fuse not found.
```

When I checked if the kernel, it had fuse enabled:

```
zgrep FUSE /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_FUSE_FS=y
```

I can't see why it isnt finding fuse. Since the kernel says its installed and I already installed all of the packages with fuse in their name from the repository

```
sudo apt-get install .fuse.
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up installing fuse from source as instructed here. 
http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2012/04/20/how-to-install-s3fs-on-an-ubuntu-server/
Ensure you go to sourceforge for the latest version